# Azure Devops hosted Ubuntu agent cancels build with edited hosts file

Tags: azure-devops, hosts-file

If I edit the hosts file using the Ubuntu agent the build just cancels all together. Had no such issue with Host Linux agent. Any ideas?

Have tried using npm package hostile to edit the hosts file, and through terminal using sudo tee.

Comment: Any errors? :^)

Comment: There was some discussion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205234/azure-devops-hosted-agent-suspicious-hosts-file) about some entries in a windows HOSTS file.  It is possible the kill might be a way to prevent circumventing blacklisted mining sites.

Comment: I did see that question and it's possible that's what they've done, but it just baffles me why they would only change it for the hosted Ubuntu agent and not Windows or Linux preview.